# Short writing in Matlab for getting the minimum of two vectors at each position

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
for i=1:length(Z1)
    if Z1(i) < Z2(i)
        min_vec(i) = Z1(i)
    else
        min_vec(i) = Z2(i)
    end
end
```

I am wondering if there is a more "matlab" short writing way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [min](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function:

If you are only interest only to the minimum value, you can simply use `Z1` and `Z2` as input:

```
min_Z1_Z2=min(Z1,Z2)
```

if you are also interested to know in which of the two array the minimun value is, you can call `min` with two parameters as output and passing as input the two array as a matrix

```
[min_val,Z1_Z2]=min([Z1;Z2])
```

In `min_val` you have the minimum value, in `Z1_Z2` the values `1` or `2` according if the min value is in the first or the second row, that is `Z1` or `Z2`

```
Z1=randi([1 33],1,10)
Z2=randi([1 33],1,10)
min_Z1_Z2=min(Z1,Z2)
[min_val,Z1_Z2]=min([Z1;Z2])


>> Z1
Z1 =

   24   12   16   21   22   15   28    7   17   29

>> Z2
Z2 =

   27   26   23    2    5   10   25   23   29    9

>> min_val
min_val =

   24   12   16    2    5   10   25    7   17    9

>> Z1_Z2
Z1_Z2 =

   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   2
```